# Equation system with multiple unknown real numbers

Tags: systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Have been having problems with this equation system for a while,
\begin{array}{l}
x - y - az = 1\\
ax + y + az = a\\
ax + 3y + 3z = -1
\end{array}
where I need to find all the values of  $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

I have tried to solve the system with elimination, by subtracting the first line multiplied by $(-a)$ with the second and third line and so on. I have found $z$ to be $\frac{-1 -a}{3+3a}$ but after integrating it and solving for $y$ I'm lost.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to  Maths.SX! Are you sure of the value found for $z$? I obtain $\frac{-1-a}{3\color{red}-3a}$.

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem

Comment: Sorry for a late response. @Bernad Yes your value of _z_ is correct. I missed a minus there thanks :)

Comment: @mfl I usually use matrixes when solving on paper but decided not to use it here as I already have the code used written in a latex document. Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Adding equation 1 and 2, we get
$$x(a+1)=a+1$$ so $$(a+1)(x-1)=0$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late response. I did manage to solve the equation finally. As Bernard also stated I had my _z_ incorrect and after doing it right I managed to find _y_ and could deduct that when _a = 1_ there are no solutions and when _a = -1_ there should be an infinite amount of solutions. 

The main problem was that I would rather think I had done something wrong than for it to be possible that _a = 1_ did not have any solutions. 

Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: If $$x=1$$ so you will get $$z(a-1)=\frac{1}{3}$$ and so $$z=\frac{1}{3(a-1)}$$ for $$a\neq 1$$

Comment: I $$a=-1$$ then there are infinity many solutions.